# Last review does not show up in review queue history nor review actions

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close, review-history

So, I did a close vote review and it was my last close vote (though still had surplus review tasks).  This was on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/126556

For me, when viewing this review (got there via back button) now I see the message:

> You have no more close votes today; come back in 9 hours.

When looking at *other* reviews that I have done I see:

> MichaelT reviewed this 10 mins ago: Close

When I look at the review query history via https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/history I don't see this review in the history (I see the one immediately prior, but not this one).

Nor do I see the review in my activity tab: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/40980/michaelt?tab=activity

I *do* see the close vote cast in my vote history: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/40980/michaelt?tab=votes&sort=closure

I believe I have seen this before - casting the last close vote on a review before running out of review tasks doesn't appear to save a review task, just the vote.

To easily reproduce this:

- Cast all but one of your close votes outside of review
- Go to /review/close
- Cast a close vote through the review queue
- Try to find that completed review in your review history

Comment: This sounds familiar. Hopefully it's a regression and not something we just ignored for like 3 years.

Comment: @Shog9 I tend to suspect the later though. I've seen it before, just this is the time I had all the items needed in my history and recent enough that I could point to it and write up a real bug report rather than "I don't think I see the review that I think I did." ... And having the event recently enough in history that its likely the devs can poke at it without having to dig up ancient things from a few builds ago.

Comment: there are two most difficult problems in programming: cache invalidation, naming and OBOE